# Save enumerator String instead of Ordinal - Envers

Tags: hibernate, grails, hibernate-envers

I'm having some trouble to have the auditing tables generated by Envers saving Enums as String instead of Ordinal type.

```
@Audited
class ElectricityProduct {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    RateType rateType

    static mapping = {
        rateType enumType: 'string'

    }

}
```

I've tried using @Enumerated annotation as well as enumType on the domain mappings and the result is the same, **an integer column is created on the DB instead of varchar to hold the enumerator representation on the electricity_product_aud table.**

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Without `@Enumerated` if the `mapping` block `rateType enumType: 'string'` should store the string value and `rateType enumType: 'ordinal'` should store the ordinal.  Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: The issue is not on ElectricityProduct table, which is generated correctly. The issue is on ElectricityProduct_AUD table generated by Envers, which is generating the column rateType as an integer and storing the ordinal value. What i want is to save the string representation instead.

Comment: Are you using a Grails plugin for envers support?

Comment: Im using org.hibernate:hibernate-envers

Comment: It's been a bit since I've looked at the code but enums should be getting stored based on the enumerated annotation and if that isn't happening then there is a bug.  Can you open an issue and attach a runnable test case based on https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/envers.

Comment: @DavidFreire, any luck?

Comment: @villager ended up not investing more time in this and going through a different solution.

Comment: @villager i've upgrated to hibernate5 and the bug is fixed, it now takes the enumType into consideration on the _aud tables.